# non-ascii characters in sqlalchemy query with caching environment

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am running into this error when I use options(FromCache()) with Sqlalchemy running on python3.6.5, dogpile.cache==0.7.1 and SQLAlchemy==1.3.2

`UnicodeEncodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can’t encode character ‘\xae’ in position 744: ordinal not in range(128)`
I figured out it's because of this the trademark in "BrandX®".

Example:

```
vendors = ['BrandX®', 'BrandY Inc.']
engine = create_engine(os.getenv('DEV_DATABASE_URL'), client_encoding='utf-8')
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False))
store_id = 123

db = Session()
q = db2.query(Order).join(Product) \
     .options(FromCache()) \
     .filter(Order.store_id == store_id) \
if vendor:
     clauses = []
     for v in vendor:
         clauses.append((Product.vendor == v))
     q = q.filter(or_(*clauses))
return q.all()
```

I tried to change the vendor encoding to 'utf-8' and 'ascii' and it's not working. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after playing around with encoding to no avail, I figured out the error is actually due to the caching. Specifically, the .options(FromCache()) is causing the problem.

I traced the error to a function called md5_key_mangler, and here's the function.

```
def md5_key_mangler(key):
"""Receive cache keys as long concatenated strings;
distill them into an md5 hash.

"""
return md5(key.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()
```

Full documentation from Sqlalchemy around [dogpile caching](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/dogpile_caching/environment.html).
It appears to be this line

```
md5(key.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()
```

that is causing the problem.
I was then able to go into the file containing my dogpile_caching.environment which I got from the attached link and change the key.encode to utf-8.

```
md5(key.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
```

And that solved the error. Hope that helps!